# <error> appearing in documentation produced by sbt doc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to generate documentation for some code I wrote in sbt/scala.

Here is the sbt configuration file

```
name := "My project"
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.2.0"
```

The documentation is being generated without errors, but the documentation files produced contain something like this:

```
def getGraph(): <error>
def getLabelMap(): HashMap[<error>, String]
def setGraph(graph: <error>): Unit
def setLabelMap(map: HashMap[<error>, String]): Unit
```

All the `<error>` fields belong to the org.apache.spark.graphx and org.apache.spark packages (in the example lines above instead of `<error>` I should get `Graph`, `VertexId`, etc).

What should I add to the sbt configuration file in order to fix this?
Cheers

Comment: I'm not very experienced with scaladoc, so I won't be able to fully answer your question, but the following page of the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Scaladoc.html) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found the answer, I had to add something like this

```
scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) := Seq(
  "-external-urls:scala=https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala",
  "-external-urls:org.apache.spark=https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/api/graphx"
)
```